# How is SQL query processed in this example?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

Purpose of this question is to find out how the inner join is used to filter out the result.
I have 2 tables, related by one column. Table `Names` contains about 100,000+ records.

```
Table: Names
+----+------+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
| 1  | A100 |
| 2  | A100 |
| 3  | A100 |
| 4  | A200 |
...

Table: TableB
+----+---------------+
| ID | ChildrenCount |
+----+---------------+
| 1  |  20           |
| 2  |  25           |
| 3  |  10           |
| 4  |  70           |
...
```

**Question 1**
Which one of these queries is more efficient?

```sql
select n.[ID]
from Names n
inner join TableB b
  on b.[ID] = n.[ID]
    and b.[ChildrenCount] > 50
where n.[Name] Like 'A%'
```

or

```sql
select n.[ID]
from Names n
inner join TableB b
  on b.[ID] = n.[ID]
    and b.[ChildrenCount] > 50
    and n.[Name] Like 'A%'
```

**Question 2**
Does [Query 1] filter out the `where` clause first and then perform inner join on the result set, or does the filtering proceed in sequential order (first inner join, then where clause)?

Comment: For an `INNER JOIN` they are equivalent (well, except for one filtering `>50` and the other `>100`), and the optimizer will end up using the same plan. For clarity and readability, you should use the first query since it is more clear what is a `JOIN` condition and what is a filter.

Comment: (1) Try them both and measure. If you find a difference, post the results here. (2) It depends, depending on other implementation details; Look at the execution plan to find out for particular tables.

Comment: Lamak: Thanks for pointing out 50 - 100 difference. I have made the conditions equal.

Comment: I agree with Pieter.  Why don't you just test them?  "One test is worth a thousand expert opinions." ;-)  Also, don't use execution plan comparisons for such things.  They can be totally incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, following relational algebra, join is applied first, and then the whole set is being filtered by WHERE clauses, so it would seem that query from first example works better.
But sql server optimizes the query, and changes order of these operation as it see fits; so these filters which can be applied before join will be applied, then goes join, and later other filters which couldn't be applied before.
Moreover, the exececution plan of both these queries should be EXACTLY the same. Check this out yourself.

Comment: Correct, Actual EPs were same. Thanks for info!

Comment: Identical execution plans can lie when it comes to performance.  Only an actual test of the code with enough rows is valid for performance comparisons.

Comment: @Jeff
Actual EP can lie if it comes to our understanding of the plan (ie plan looks great, but performs poorly). But two same (actual execution) plans will perform the same (effective or not), and that was the point of this question.

Comment: That's right, @frikozoid! The question was about whether their performance is same or not. But also, I need to know if the ordering of conditions would matter or not. There are multiple ideas floating around and I need to know the standard way. If MSDN says - Order does/doesn't matter - I would be happy with that answer.

Comment: Not quite right.  Two identical execution plans can vary quite a bit by performance.  % of batch can lie like a rug even on the actual execution plans because even the actual execution plans contains estimates. I don't believe I can come up with an example where they match on short notice but I can show you where it's totally backwards to performance.  I'll try to find that example in my archives and post it.